# Apex- Set Picklist Field Selected Value

Tags: salesforce, apex, picklist

I have a picklist field in some object. And, through apex, I want to set the selected value of the picklist. When I try to do that, it says "bad value for restricted picklist field:".
but the value I am trying to set is there in the value set. And I have enabled "Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set" too.

```
     MyObject.MyPickListField = 'Belgium';
```

May I know where I have gone wrong in setting the picklist field's selected value ?

Comment: Can you share your value set ?

Comment: Hi ! It's like this.  'Belgium','Canada', 'Sri Lanka'. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: These are labels. Do you think I need to assign the value instead ?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, remove the default value from the Record Type or picklist field (depending on where it is set).

**Remove the default value: Record Type**

**Lightning Experience instructions:**

- Select the Gear icon | Setup
- Click Object Manager
- Select the Object for the Record Type that contains the picklist
- Select Record Types
- Select Record Type that contains the picklist
- Click Edit for the picklist you wish to change
- In the 'Default' field, select --None--
- Click Save

**Salesforce Classic instructions:**

- Select Setup | Customize
- Select the Object containing the Picklist, then select Record Types
- Click the name of the Record Type that contains the picklist
- Click Edit for the picklist you wish to change
- In the 'Default' field, select --None--
- Click Save

**Remove the default value: Picklist**

**Lightning Experience instructions:**

- Select the Gear icon | Setup
- Click Object Manager
- Select the Object that contains the picklist
- Select Fields and Relationships
- Select the picklist field you wish to change
- Click Edit for the picklist value that is set as the Default
- Deselect the 'Default' checkbox. Note: Make this value the default for the master picklist.
- Click Save

**Salesforce Classic instructions:**

- Select Setup | Customize
- Select the Object containing the picklist, then select Fields
- Select the picklist field you wish to change
- Click Edit for the picklist value that is set as the Default
- Deselect the 'Default' checkbox. Note: Make this value the default for the master picklist.
- Click Save